# What is the best way to handle GraphQl response in Java

Tags: java, rest, graphql, resttemplate, graphql-java

In a legacy application with Java 6 I am calling a GraphQl API using Spring RestTemplate, now I would like to know what is the best way to handle the response, once GraphQl always will give a response with StatusCode 200 in case of success or error and the difference is that inside the body response there will be a string with "data" for success and "errors" for errors.
I was thinking that I can get the response and convert to String and check using "contains" and check if there is "data" or "errors" inside the response body, but I do not know if it is the best way.
The code below is how the Java application is calling the GraphQl API:

```
ResponseEntity<?> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, String.class);
```

The way that I thought to handle is:

```
if (response.getBody().toString().contains("errors")){
    handleException
}
```

Comment: handleException would be :  returning new ResponseEntity(T body, MultiValueMap<String, String> headers, HttpStatus status)

Comment: Tks TechFree, but my doubt is about if I should use this condition "response.getBody().toString().contains("errors")" to check if there is erros or there is another better way.

Comment: clearly, you shouldn't do it like that. I agree with @Ken_Chan answer.

Answer (score 2):

GraphQL will give the response body in the following `JSON` format

```
{
  "data": { ... },
  "errors": [ ... ]
}
```

If there were errors , it will have an errors fields.

So , it is a bad idea as you are checking if the whole JSON response contains an `errors` string rather than `errors` field. It will definitely fail for the success case just because `data` contains a `errors` string (e.g Think about it is a get user request but an user use `errors` as his login ID)

You should parse the response body into the JSON object and check if the JSON contains a field called `errors` or not.

If you have `Jackson` in the class path , `RestTemplate` will detect it and auto configure itself to be able to parse JSON which allows you to do something like:

```
ResponseEntity<Map<String,Object>> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, Map.class);
Map<String,Object> body = response.getBody();
if(body.containsKey("errors")){
   //handleException
}
```